# Why is sympathy so much more expensive than antipathy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, spell-components

[*Antipathy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antipathy.htm) and [*sympathy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sympathy.htm) are both spells of the same level (Clr 9, Sor/Wiz 8). They have basically opposite effects, and they counter & dispel each other, yet *antipathy* is free (requiring components without a listed cost), while *sympathy* isn't (requiring a crushed pearl worth **1,500 gp**). I could never understand this difference.

I can imagine constraining a creature to an area can be more useful than just keeping it out of an area but otherwise free to act normally. Still, this doesn't seem to me a difference big enough to warrant such a huge cost difference.

Is there a use (or pattern of uses) which makes *sympathy* dramatically better or more effective? Or is there a different reason for the gap in costs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It's a Trap! Sort Of.

Not in the [traditional sense](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/traps.htm), but the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*sympathy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/sympathy.htm) [ench] (*PH* 292) is *bait* for a trap. Pick the kind of intelligent creature or pick an opposed alignment and lie in wait. Unlike most spells, the spell *sympathy* brings the adventure to the PCs, consequently--potentially!--enabling access to treasure without need for exploration, giving necromancers easy access to valuable corpses, and permitting contact with local fauna that could serve as allies if an *unopposed* alignment's chosen.

The ability to gather in one area *actual* creatures whose race or alignment the caster knows *is* more valuable than sending away the same. There are a huge variety of ways to kill or drive away creatures in *Dungeons and Dragons*, yet very few ways to *force* encounters. The spell *sympathy* permits the caster to do just that.

I'm speculating hard here, but I assume that was Gygax's concern with the spell originally, and why the spell *sympathy* (and its earlier iterations) has always had an expensive material component, [a tradition *Pathfinder* continues](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sympathy).

### Previous Editions

Both *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* and *Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition* combined the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*antipathy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antipathy.htm) [ench] (*PH* 200) and the spell *sympathy* into the single spell *antipathy/sympathy* on page 89 of the *Player's Handbook* (1978) and *antipathy-sympathy* (1989) on page 238 of the *Player's Handbook* (1989), respectively. Both of the earlier spells' *sympathy* uses required 1,000 gp of crushed pearls and a drop of honey as material components, while the the antipathy uses were merely a lump of [alum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alum) soaked in vinegar.

(Why the spell went from needing 1,000 gp of crushed pearls to *1,500* gp of crushed pearls is a mystery. Thinking it might be related to gem rarity in *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition*, I checked the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) on Table 7-5: Gems (172), where the most valuable black pearl is worth an average of 500 gp and, at most, 800 gp. So that's *not* it. I'm unaware of an official explanation.)

Comment: Your point about there being many more spells for driving creatures away than luring them in is certainly valid and very interesting; it's definitely one I haven't thought of.